# Programming C8051F020 in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: wine, 16.10, ide, embedded-system

I need to program the c8051f020 microcontroller on Ubuntu 16.10.
I have yet Silicon Labs IDE through Wine and Simplicity Studio, but they doesn't work.

The first one not recognize the USB debug adapter and the second one doesn't support C8051F0xx family.

I'd prefer to not use a Windows VM cause of my little RAM.

Can anyone help me make adapter working on Silicon Labs IDE? 
If not anyone have any idea or can advise me another software to do it ?

Comment: I'm completely new to this world but a moment's googling turned up this: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/mcu8051ide/

Comment: WINE doesn't support USB...

Comment: but i think that it will be surely be a solution or an alternative